# Reveal Timestamp React Native (iMessage Clone)

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I was wondering how I would go about dragging/sliding left to reveal the timestamp on react native. I am using a flatlist in react-native and I have the timestamp data but I am unsure of how to render the timestamps on slight drag. Anyone have detailed ideas on how to do this. I have included images of current implementation and iMessage slide/drag. This feature is also on Instagram (ios version at least). I should add that I'm not trying to do a drag and drop feature more like just a solution review what is not currently in the view from a slide/drag

[Current App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrFup.png)
[Current iMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDuQ7.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the eventual solution i came up with all credit from @Abe and reading the gesture-handler documentation referenced above. I

```
import Animated, { useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withSpring } from 'react-native-reanimated'
  const translateX = useSharedValue(0)
  const startX = useRef(0)
```

My flatlist renders elements like this now

```
    <Animated.View
        className="mx-2  flex-1 flex-row"
        style={sty}
        onTouchStart={(e) => {
          startX.current = e.nativeEvent.pageX
        }}
        onTouchMove={(e) => {
          const delta = startX.current - e.nativeEvent.pageX
          if (delta > 0) {
            translateX.value = -delta / 2
          }
        }}
        onTouchEnd={() => {
          translateX.value = withSpring(0)
        }}>
...
</Animated.View>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to handle this is with a [PanGestureHandler from react-native-gesture-handler](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/gesture-handlers/api/pan-gh/) and an [Animated.View from react-native-reanimated](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation).

Wrap your component in one, and make the View that you want to move into an Animated.View. (The component that the PanGestureHandler wraps also should be an Animated.View.) Create a shared value (from Reanimated) that represents the x offset of the component. Then create a handler method that responds to the drag gesture and changes the shared value. You may want to add some limits, like not scrolling past a certain offset in either direction. Then, use the shared value in an animated style (something like `left: offsetX,`) that you apply to your Animated.View.

Since you're using this inside a scrollable list, make sure to set the [activeOffsetX](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/gesture-handlers/api/pan-gh/#activeoffsetx) prop to something like `[-5, 5]`. This means that if the user is only trying to scroll up and down, your gesture handler won't steal that touch.

[The example in the gesture-handler docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/gesture-handlers/api/pan-gh/#example) should help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I played around with this and used it to form my own solution. I want to accept the answer but I didnt end up using that library in the final solution although i used the reanimated lib like you suggested. Thanks a lot

Comment: @thethrdxer can you provide a snack/gist of the solution? Your example does not shift the entire list, just per message, right? Thanks